# Obtener el número de documentos modificados con un update en Meteor

Tags: meteor

Tengo un método en Meteor que hace un update. El update funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, me gustaría recoger un OK o similar para ver que el update se ha realizado correctamente e informar al usuario (o escribir en log).

La [documentación de Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update) dice que la función devuelve el número de documentos modificados y que a la llamada de un update se le puede añadir una función de Callback, con el error como primer parámetro y el número de documentos afectados como segundo parámetro.

He intentado, sin éxito, recoger ese valor. Mi llamada es

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {"profile.user_preferences": userProfilePreferencesDTO}});
```

que devuelve "undefined" donde un insert me devuelve el _id generado para el documento.

Si añado la función de Callback entonces, dentro de esa función, sí que tengo el número de documentos modificados, pero mi método en meteor no parece tener esa información fuera del callback.

He encontrado [esta incidencia en github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3349), que fue cerrada el mismo día que se abrió, que dice que . Otros artículos que he podido encontrar dicen que *upsert* funciona correctamente en ese sentido, pero que *update* no, a pesar de que la documentación oficial dice que el método devuelve el número de documentos modificados.

Mi pregunta entonces: Cómo obtener le número de documentos afectados por un update en Meteor (si es que es posible?).

Answer (score 1):

la solución a tu error puede ser si lo haces del lado del cliente

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {"profile.user_preferences": userProfilePreferencesDTO}}, function(error, result) { if (!error) { alert("actualizado documento: " + result) } });
```

Y del lado del servidor en un método

```
myMethod: function() {
   return Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {"profile.user_preferences": userProfilePreferencesDTO}});
}
```